# Windows phone 7 deploying apps to device

Tags: windows-phone-7

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) Says "You can deploy up to ten apps on a registered device" Is that mean that I can Use to test my one App for ten times only or Ten App any Time ?

Comment: The number of deployed applications will be limited to 10. The apps, that were installed from the market doesn't count, only the ones, you deploy via Visual Studio debugging or Windows Phone SDK -> "application deployment".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only means that you can install up to ten app that you developped on a registered device. Once this limit is reached you wiil get this error message :

> "The maximum number of developer applications on this phone has been
>   reached"

The solution is simply to remove one developer app and try again.
Of course, you can test your app on 20 differents devcies (if you have them).